# Add custom attributes to logging-channel-adapter Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-integration

I have the following configuration:

```
<int:channel id="responseXmlChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="responseXmlLogger" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="responseXmlLogger"
                             logger-name="test.SyncResponseLogger" level="DEBUG"
                             expression="'message received, headers:' + headers + ' payload:' + payload"/>
```

I am trying to add some session attributes to be logged. Current user for example.
I was taking a look at the `header-enricher` approach, but I could not find a good example of adding session attributes to the header using it.

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do? Is there other approach besides using the headers to add custom attributes to be logged?

My goal is to have in the logs something like

current user: $UserName. Payload: $Payload

Comment: Show us, please, how do you get access to those session attributes at all?

Comment: I do have access by using a custom service class that handles the session attribute. But this is just an example. If I find a way to add a custom attribute at all, by accessing a custom service class that I have for example, it will do. Maybe the session attribute that I am trying to use was not a good example.

Answer (score 0):

OK. So, what is your question then? How to use `header-enricher`? I'm not sure what is your "session" object to be precise with the answer, but `header-enricher` can be configured to call any arbitrary method on beans. See its docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-transformation.html#header-enricher.

The other approach is too deal with `ThreadLocal`. That's exactly what the `RequestContextHolder` in Spring Web does for `RequestAttributes` with its HTTP session access. Although you need to keep in mind that moving to a different thread with queue or executor channels in between will lose the current thread context and you won't have access to that `ThreadLocal`. So, headers in the particular message is not so bad choice to do.